# Facebook Application Tab On Page Not Working

Tags: facebook

I have a working facebook fbml application tab on a page. It was working perfectly but today when i checked it was generating an error.

```
Errors while loading page from application
Parse errors:

FBML Error (line 18): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

FBML Error (line 26): illegal tag "noscript" under "fb:tab-position"

FBML Error (line 44): illegal tag "noscript" under "fb:tab-position"

Runtime errors:

HTML error while rendering tag "link": There is a hard limit of 2 css link tags on profile tabs in order to remain under the IE 31 tag limit.

HTML error while rendering tag "link": There is a hard limit of 2 css link tags on profile tabs in order to remain under the IE 31 tag limit.

Cannot allow external script
```

My settings are:

> Canvas Page URL: http://apps.facebook.com/myfeedback/
>   
>   Canvas Callback URL: `http://mydomain/myfile/`
>   
>   Tab Name: Feedback
>   
>   Tab URL: http://apps.facebook.com/myfeedback/

This is an fbml application without any body tags

I am unable to find out the reason for the same. Please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a FBML app/tab, the `body` tag is not allowed. You should remove that and you will be fine. Here is the sample:

**This is not allowed:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
     <!-- your layout code -->
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is allowed:**

```
  <table>
     <!-- your layout code -->
  </table>
```

Comment: @Pankaj: I saw this error in your question `FBML Error (line 18): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"` which means you have it somewhere in your code, check in any included files, also check in page source.

Comment: i have checked everywhere there is no body tag.

Comment: @Pankaj: hmm strange may be this is because they have changed their api again, checkout new graph api here: http://graph.facebook.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. It was caused by some rules written in the .htaccess file present in the root directory(mydomain). I have written a rule for excluding the myfile folder.
The rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfile/
```

Now the page is loaded without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your *Canvas Type* to **IFrame** at the bottom of **Advanced Settings** tab.